# Multiple vertex types in JUNG

Tags: java, jung

I need to make a graph that will support multiple vertex types (3 to be exact) and I've been trying to find an example that does this with JUNG except I can seem to find one.  Does anyone know of any examples that do this that I can look at?  And anything that places the different vertices using different mouse clicks would be awesome as well (ie left click to place a vertex of type 1, shift left click to place a vertex of type 2, etc).  Thanks.

Comment: When you say "multiple vertex types" do you mean "multiple different vertex shapes" (as in your previous question) or that you want the actual Java type of the vertex in the graph to be one of multiple options?

Comment: Completely different type.  For example, some vertices are cars, some people, and some houses.  Thus the vertices would have totally different properties associated with them.

Answer (score 0):

You've basically got two options:

(1)

```
Graph<V extends YourVertexSuperClass, E>
```

In this case I'm assuming you've got something like

```
public interface YourVertexSuperClass { ... }
public class Car implements YourVertexSuperClass { ... }
public class Person implements YourVertexSuperClass { ... }
```

etc.

(The interface could be an abstract class, of course.)

This probably only really makes sense if your vertex types have something in common.

(2)

```
Graph<? extends Object, E>
```

In this case you can put anything in, i.e., no type restrictions.